# Graph of the function $x^y - z^2x + z^2y - y^x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I know the basic graph and shifting the graphs. But I have a special equation. I will explain the specialty of the functions later. Okay...let me say the specialty. This function has infinitely many solutions. I would like to know the GRAPH of the function. I can't draw the graph of this function. Please use computer and show me the picture/ graph of the following functions. Once again thank you for this wonderful site and members of this site.

The function is:$$x^y - z^2x + z^2y - y^x = 0.$$

Also, I want to know that, what kind of function it is? I mean, is it elliptic curve? or something else....

Comment: Not an elliptic curve. The equation determines a surface, and with appropriate software one can sketch that surface.  Very little of a general nature is known about equations that mix variable exponents with polynomials.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Can you draw the graph of this function please....

Comment: If this is homework you are probably supposed to create a graph on your own, what software do you use?

Comment: Sir,
I am using MATLAB software. Unfortunately, I am not able to draw. Please could you draw this graph...

Comment: @Later Please don't make cosmetic edits to old questions. That moves them to the active queue and distracts from genuinely active questions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
&&x^y-z^2 x+z^2 y-y^x&=0 \\
&\implies&x^y-y^x-z^2(x-y)&=0 \\
&\implies&x^y-y^x&=z^2(x-y) \\
&\implies&\frac{x^y-y^x}{x-y}&=z^2 \\
&\implies&z=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^y-y^x}{x-y}}&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{x^y-y^x}}{\sqrt{x-y}} \\
\end{align}$$

[Applying WolframAlpha to $z=\frac{\sqrt{x^y-y^x}}{\sqrt{x-y}}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%5Ey-y%5Ex%29/sqrt%28x-y%29) (just the $+$ part, not the $-$ part) shows several visualizations.